# How to get object from Request POST object with Angular Ajax call in NODEJS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

1. After click the button will call a method .. The code is,

   ```
       .controller('templeDetailsList', function ($scope, $http, $ionicModal) {

        $scope.starclick = function(){

        var newFav = [{
               "favid":"4654646",
               "favname":"sometext"
           }];

        var favurl = "http://localhost:1337/users/adduser";

        $.post(favurl, newFav, function () {
               alert("Successfully posted data");
           });
       }

       });
   ```
2. Node service with mongodb code is,

   ```
       var express = require('express');

       var router = express();

       router.post('/adduser', function (req, res) {

       var db = req.db;

       var d1 = req.body;

       var collection = db.get('userlist');
       collection.insert(req.body, function (err, result) {
           res.send(
               (err === null) ? { msg: '' } : { msg: err }
           );
       });
       });
   ```

   Http request succesfully worked for to calling service method. But i can't get request object in service method. What can i do for this?. I want get requesting object data in service method. please anyone help to me.

Answer (score 0):

Add [body parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) to your express app.

```
var router = express();
bodyParser = require('body-parser');
router.use(bodyParser.json());
```